# How can I find out the ID of the channel a user is on using the slack API?

Tags: api, global, slack, shortcut, channel

I need for my bot, when the user uses the global shortcut, to find out the ID of the channel on which it is located. But in the payload when using app .shortcut, the channel id is not specified. I need the channel ID to display information to the user when he clicks on the shortcut for the channel on which he is currently. How can I solve this problem.
Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

So as per this bit of [documentation](https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/shortcuts) the _channel id is only part of the payload for **message shortcuts**, so you will not get that information for a global shortcut.

A potential workaround could be to use a workflow step? Users can still summon the functionality with the same approach, typing /some_name, but you'll get channel information.

Here is the [workflow steps documentation](https://api.slack.com/workflows/steps)